# encryption for short messages

Tags: encryption

Are there any algorithms/modes that work particularly well for shorter messages? (hundreds of bytes at most, usually < 100 bytes).  I am looking at it from both security and performance point of view.

I imagine padding a short message to block size isn't good for performance, and seem to recall there being crypto problems if you don't do padding a particular way.  Does that mean that streaming mode would be inherently better for my scenario than a block mode?

Comment: What is the security problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: No 'problem' just trying to see how I can make it better/faster/not set myself up for any crypto hackery that might be a result of not having longer messages.